# Probability of Frequency of independent Event

Tags: probability

Suppose that we have the event $A$. The event $A$ has probability of occurance $p$, i.e $P(A)=p$. We conduct $N$ independent experiments, and we denoted as $X$ the frequency of occurance of event $A$.

I would like to know if the following is correct:

$P(X=x)=p^{X}$

Comment: In short, No. It makes no sense to speak of the probability of frequency. It does make sense to speak of probability that a certain event will occur. The frequentist definition of probability says that with independent repetitions of an identical experiment the probability of a certain event occurring equals the limit of the relative frequency of the event, as the number of repetitions of the experiment goes to infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your definition, $X$ seems to be random variable so $P(X)$ doesn't make sense. But, probability of $X$ being equal to a particular number, say $x$, makes sense, i.e. $P(X=x)$, and your question can be reworded as:

> Is $P(X=x)=p^x$

At each independent trial, A either occurs or not, e.g. coin toss is our trial and $A$ is the event that the coin ends up Heads. Then, $X$ is a binomial random variable and

$$P(X=x)={N\choose x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$$

Comment: That's what I was thinking about. And if we have more than one event, we can generalize that to a multinomial?

Comment: Correct, even in this case, you have two events $A$ and $A'$

Comment: @Fiodor1234: Multinomial is a generalization of the binomial not when there are more than one event (that doesn't make sense) but when the sample space for each trial/experiment includes more than 2 outcomes.

Comment: @ColorStatistics I was thinking that events and outcomes are the same things.

Comment: Outcomes are the most granular elements of the sample space. In rolling a die the sample space is made up of the following outcomes {1,2,3,4,5,6}. Events are subsets of the sample space, including the empty set and the entire sample space, and the outcomes. The following are all legitimate events: {1},{4},{1,3,5},{1,2,3,4,5,6}, {}.